# Teradata SQL: Search for the first time a value changes in a column

Tags: sql, teradata, gaps-and-islands

So, I have a table that tracks customer accounts on a daily basis and records values for each business day, such as the balance on that account.

For example:

```
Acct_Nbr   Acct_Open_Date   System_Date   Balance
-------------------------------------------------
111        2017-12-01       2017-12-01    0.00
111        2017-12-01       2017-12-04    0.00
111        2017-12-01       2017-12-05    0.00
111        2017-12-01       2017-12-06    500.00
222        2017-12-01       2017-12-01    0.00
222        2017-12-01       2017-12-04    0.00
222        2017-12-01       2017-12-05    0.00
222        2017-12-01       2017-12-06    0.00
222        2017-12-01       2017-12-07    0.00
222        2017-12-01       2017-12-08    250.00
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return the # of days between Acct_Open_Date and the System_Date on which the Balance first became > 0 (i.e. the date the account got funded).

I plan on grouping the # of days in buckets, using a `case when` statement (i.e. <=5 days, 6-10 days, etc.) and for each bucket return the # of accounts.

Based on the table above, it would return:

```
Time_to_fund   Count_of_accts
-----------------------------
<=5 days       1
6-10 days      1
>10 days       0
```

I'm not entirely sure how to write a query that will search on a per account basis through each row until it finds a value for Balance > 0, and then takes the System_Date for that row and subtracts the Acct_Open_Date from that to give me # of days.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   CASE WHEN diff <=  5 THEN'<=5 days'
        when diff <= 10 then '6-10 days'
        ELSE '>10 days'
   END as Time_to_fund,
   COUNT(*)
from
 (
    select
       System_Date - Acct_Open_Date as diff -- number of days between
    from mytable
    where Balance > 0 
    qualify -- find the first row with a Balance > 5
       row_number()
       over (partition by Acct_Nbr
             order by System_Date) = 1
 ) as dt
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something with a window function, just still haven't been able to fully wrap my head around how those work.  But if I understand it correctly, what your query does is it excludes all rows with system_dates = 0, finds the first row (which will be 1 because of the row_number() function, correct?) and groups it by Acct_Nbr and then orders by system_date so that the first row is the first date where the account got funded.  Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @starfly Exactly. 1: remove all 0 rows, 2: for each Acct_Nbr, order all rows by System_Date and return the 1st (=oldest) row only. If the Acct_Open_Date was not included it would be a bit more complicated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GROUP BY within a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN fund_times.Time_to_fund_in_days<= 5 THEN'<=5 days'
when fund_times.Time_to_fund_in_days<= 10 then '6-10 days'
ELSE '>10 days' END as Time_to_fund, COUNT(fund_times.acct_Number) AS Count_of_accts
    (SELECT t.acct_Number, MIN( (t.System_Date - t.Acct_Open_Date) * 86400) as Time_to_fund_in_days
    from table as T
    WHERE t.Balance>0
    GROUP BY t.acct_Number) AS fund_times
GROUP BY CASE WHEN fund_times.Time_to_fund_in_days<= 5 THEN'<=5 days'
when fund_times.Time_to_fund_in_days<= 10 then '6-10 days'
ELSE '>10 days' END
```